# Serilog: Missing logs when logging with simple for loop

Tags: logging, .net-core, serilog

I have started using Serilog and written test *Dot Net Core 3.1 Console application*.

In my simple project, I am looping and logging. Serilog logs on *Console* and *File*.

But I found that logs are getting missed after 10,000 log entries. Till 10,000 log entries, all logs are sequences in both Console and File, but after 10,000 entries, logs starting to miss on both *Console* and *File*. For example, 29483 after 10000.

Also, function call Log.CloseAndFlush() to flush all logs isn't working as i don't see log entry "FINISHED" in the end of *Console* and *File*.

```
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:1
........ Logs are in sequencial order ........
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:9993
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:9994
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:9995
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:9996
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:9997
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:9998
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:9999
2020-05-26 12:12:38.575 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:10000
2020-05-26 12:12:38.637 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:29483
2020-05-26 12:12:38.689 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:62627
2020-05-26 12:12:38.693 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:64740
2020-05-26 12:12:38.694 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:65624
2020-05-26 12:12:38.695 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:66169
2020-05-26 12:12:38.697 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:66662
2020-05-26 12:12:38.697 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:67040
2020-05-26 12:12:38.698 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:67432
2020-05-26 12:12:38.698 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:67828
2020-05-26 12:12:38.699 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:68083
2020-05-26 12:12:38.700 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:68386
2020-05-26 12:12:38.700 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:68756
2020-05-26 12:12:38.701 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:69387
2020-05-26 12:12:38.702 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:69904
2020-05-26 12:12:38.703 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:70296
2020-05-26 12:12:38.703 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:70681
2020-05-26 12:12:38.704 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:71093
2020-05-26 12:12:38.706 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:72488
2020-05-26 12:12:38.706 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:72945
2020-05-26 12:12:38.707 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:73590
2020-05-26 12:12:38.708 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:73975
2020-05-26 12:12:38.708 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:74383
2020-05-26 12:12:38.709 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:74783
2020-05-26 12:12:38.709 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:75183
2020-05-26 12:12:38.711 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:75644
2020-05-26 12:12:38.712 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:76087
2020-05-26 12:12:38.713 | [INFO] | Thread-1 | hello:76719
```

I was looking at issues faced by other developers on missing logs but none of them relates to my issue.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using System;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var l_config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

            Logger l_log = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(l_config).CreateLogger();
            Log.Logger = l_log;

            for (long l_index = 0; l_index < 100000L; l_index++)
            {
                Log.Information("hello:" + l_index);
            }
            Log.Information("FINISHED");
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        ~Program()
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.Console"],
        "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
        "WriteTo": [{
                "Name": "Async",
                "Args": {
                    "configure": [{
                            "Name": "Console",
                            "Args": {
                                "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
                                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} | [{Level:u4}] | Thread-{ThreadId} | {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                            }                           
                        }, {
                            "Name": "File",
                            "Args": {
                                "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
                                "path": "Logs\\log..txt",                               
                                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} | [{Level:u4}] | Thread-{ThreadId} | {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                                "rollingInterval": "Hour",
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithThreadId"],
        "Destructure": [{
                "Name": "ToMaximumDepth",
                "Args": {
                    "maximumDestructuringDepth": 4
                }
            }, {
                "Name": "ToMaximumStringLength",
                "Args": {
                    "maximumStringLength": 100
                }
            }, {
                "Name": "ToMaximumCollectionCount",
                "Args": {
                    "maximumCollectionCount": 10
                }
            }
        ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": "MyApp"
        }
    }
}
```

Using Nuget packages:

- Serilog.dll
- Serilog.Enrichers.Environment.dll
- Serilog.Enrichers.Thread.dll
- Serilog.Settings.Configuration.dll
- Serilog.Sinks.Async.dll
- Serilog.Sinks.Console.dll

I apologize for putting lot of info here but that's needed so we can pin point the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the buffer size feeding `Async()` is fixed at 10,000 items by default, and does not block when full.

To change this, add `blockWhenFull: true`:

```
    "WriteTo": [{
            "Name": "Async",
            "Args": {
                "blockWhenFull": true,
                "configure": [{
```

More info [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async/#buffering--dropping) and [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-async/#blocking).